# Series of variables in a loop using index

Tags: ios, swift, loops

I have a number of variables that I want to update as follows (this works ok)

```
answer1Yes = answer1Yes+1
answer2Yes = answer2Yes+1
answer3Yes = answer3Yes+1
answer4Yes = answer4Yes+1
answer5Yes = answer5Yes+1
```

I’m trying to put this into a loop as follows (this doesn’t work)

```
for index in 1...5 {
    answer(index)Yes = answer(index)Yes+1
    }
```

Can you please advise correct syntax for this.

Comment: Variable names cannot be dynamic because they are evaluated at compile time

Comment: You should use an array.

Comment: You might wanna use a `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this behaviour, you could use an array.
Consider the following code:

```
var answers = [0,0,0,0,0]

for index in 0..<answers.count {
    answers[index] += 1
}
print(answers)
```

So now your variables are represented by the elements inside of the array and you can simply loop through them.

Comment: You should (almost) never write `0..<answers.count`. See https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Proper%20Array%20Iteration.md#for-i-in-0arraycount-

Comment: Thanks for the link!